# Devices drawing current

Tags: current, charging, plug

I was recently reading a passage discussing the effects of a replacement (mobile phone) charging plug.

Suppose that the original charging plug is marked 2 A and 10 V and is replaced with a charging plug marked 1 A and 10 V. Although the replacement plug supplies the same charge, the immediate disadvantage is that charging time would increase. However, a lower current would lead to reduced heating effect but the additional point identified is "the phone may draw a current of 2 A which may damage the charger".

Can someone explain what is meant by "draw" in this case and in what way is the charging plug damaged. Just to note: I'm not disagreeing with the statement I just require some clarification.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add links to the document(s) containing the text which  you are quoting, please? Thanks.

Comment: By "charging plug" I suspect that you mean "charger". The charging plug would generally be considered to be the micro USB plug that goes into the phone. You might want to clarify that in your post.

Comment: No, the passage stated "charging plug" not "charger" I don't have a copy of it as I read it as a printed document. It included pictures of what would appear to look like "chargers ".

Answer (score 1):

Your phone has in internal battery charger which controls how it charges its battery.

Based on what you have said it is capable of using (or drawing) enough power from the charger that the original charger was rated at 2A (2 amperes).

If you use a charger capable of (in this case) only 1 ampere, then it is possible that the phone may "draw" more than the 1A the charger is rated at, which may cause the charger to overheat (as it 'attempts' to provide more than it is designed for).

Answer (score 0):

The phone's charge controller manages the charging of your phone's battery. If you use a charger with a large output current, then in any case, the charge controller will control the current consumption.

But I know of cases when replacing the original charger with a more powerful one, the charging circuits of the device failed. For example, the gamepad dualshoсk 4 from the playtation 4 when it charged by powerbank.

I can not say what it is exactle connected with, but it is better to use chargers with the characteristics recommended by the device manufacturer.